# How to 301 redirect to remove ending / on asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, redirect, http-status-code-301

In order to prevent duplicity on my `category` pages I want to redirect those ending with `/` to without:

```
from - www.domain.com/category/
to   - www.domain.com/category
```

I'm using standard web forms.

Please advise,

Thanks.

Comment: You want to do only for this URL or you have dynamic url with '/'?

Comment: Dynamic - @Bhavesh Kachhadiya your answer was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In global.asax file add following code:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().EndsWith("/category/"))
    {
        string sNewPage = Request.Url.ToString().ToLower().TrimEnd('/');

        Response.Clear();
        Response.Status = "301 Moved Permanently";
        Response.AddHeader("Location", sNewPage);
        Response.End();
    }
}
```